# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar

Tags: spring, docker, maven

Help, I'm trying to upload the spring boot application to fly.io

```
2022-12-27T18:13:45Z   [info]Preparing to run: `java -jar /app.jar` as root
2022-12-27T18:13:45Z   [info]2022/12/27 18:13:45 listening on [fdaa:1:12ef:a7b:a0:3feb:41aa:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
2022-12-27T18:13:45Z   [info]Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar
2022-12-27T18:13:46Z   [info]Starting clean up.
--> v45 failed - Failed due to unhealthy allocations - not rolling back to stable job version 45 as current job has same specification and deploying as v46 

--> Troubleshooting guide at https://fly.io/docs/getting-started/troubleshooting/
Error abort
```

```
FROM ibm-semeru-runtimes:open-17-jre-focal
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE= ./target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tasf</groupId>
    <artifactId>prueba</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>prueba</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...     
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

buid
BUILD SUCCESS
Total time:  10.109 s
Finished at: 2022-12-27T13:20:04-05:00
he requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.

Comment: Is the error what happens when building the dockerfile? Both locally, and on fly.io? Isolate the problem by building oustide of Docker, then Docker locally, then on the remote build server.

Answer (score 0):

the .dockerignore file was ignoring the /target path